# How to correctly mock setState with React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I am trying to use React Testing Library to mock the `setState` function from my `index.js` file in React.

I have two text inputs where if the passwords don't match, a `setInputError` state should be called to notify a user the passwords don't match when trying to register, but when trying to write tests for this the number of calls is '0'.

This is my `index.js` file:

```
const [inputError, setInputError] = useState({
        email: false,
        confirmEmail: false,
        password: false,
        confirmPassword: false,
        passwordMatch: false,
    });

const checkInputErrors = useCallback(
        (inputPassword, confirmInputPassword) => {
            const inputError = {
                passwordMatch: inputPassword !== confirmInputPassword,
                password: !checkPassword(inputPassword),
                confirmPassword: inputPassword !== confirmInputPassword || confirmInputPassword === "",
            };

            return inputError;
        },
        []
    );

const registerAccountHandler = useCallback(async () => {
        const inputError = checkInputErrors(
            inputPassword,
            confirmInputPassword,
        );
        const inputErrorFound = Object.values(inputError).some((error) => error);

        if (inputErrorFound) {
            setInputError(inputError);
            return;
        }

        const { error } = await register({
            password: inputPassword,
        });

        if (!error) {
            historyObject.replace("/subscribe/plans");
        } else {
            toast.error(t(`error.${error.data?.title}`, error.data?.title));
        }
    }, [
        t,
        register,
        inputPassword,
        confirmInputEmail,
        confirmInputPassword,
        checkInputErrors,
    ]);


 <div className={"input-container"}>
                        <TextField
                            title={t("pages.login.signup.password")}
                            label={t("pages.login.signup.confirm_password_placeholder")}
                            value={inputPassword}
                            onChange={(val) => {
                                setInputPassword(val);
                                setInputError(false);
                            }}
                            validation={inputError.password && { status: validationStatuses.ERROR }}
                        />
                        {renderCriteriaMetNotifications}
                        <TextField
                            title={t("pages.login.signup.confirm_password")}
                            label={t("pages.login.signup.confirm_password_placeholder")}
                            value={confirmInputPassword}
                            onChange={(val) => {
                                setConfirmInputPassword(val);
                                setInputError(false);
                            }}
                            validation={inputError.confirmPassword && { status: validationStatuses.ERROR }}
                        />
                       
                    </div>
```

and my test file where I am trying to mock the `setState` for the `passwordMatch` to `true` if there is an error:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import SignupPage from "./index";
import * as redux from "react-redux";
jest.mock("historyObject");
jest.mock("services/api/login");
import { loginApiService } from "services/api/login";
// import { historyObject } from "historyObject";

describe("SignupPage", () => {
    const props = {
        t: jest.fn(),
        inputError: {
            email: false,
            confirmEmail: false,
            password: false,
            confirmPassword: false,
            passwordMatch: false,
            acceptTerms: false,
        },
        setInputError: jest.fn(),
    };

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetAllMocks();
        jest.spyOn(React, "useEffect")
            .mockImplementationOnce((x) => x())
            .mockImplementationOnce((x) => x())
            .mockImplementationOnce((x) => x())
            .mockImplementationOnce((x) => x());
        // loginApiService.useUserSignupMutation.mockReturnValue({ data: undefined });
        loginApiService.useUserSignupMutation.mockReturnValue([jest.fn(), { isLoading: false }]);
    });


it("should display error message when passwords do not match", async () => {
        const setInputError = jest.fn();
        const props = { setInputError };
        const { getByLabelText, getByText } = render(<SignupPage {...props} />);
        const passwordInput = getByLabelText("pages.login.signup.password");
        const confirmPasswordInput = getByLabelText("pages.login.signup.confirm_password");
        const registerButton = getByText("pages.login.signup.register");
        fireEvent.change(passwordInput, { target: { value: "password1" } });
        fireEvent.change(confirmPasswordInput, { target: { value: "password2" } });
        fireEvent.click(registerButton);

        // expect inputError to be true for passwordMatch
        expect(setInputError).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            ...props.inputError,
            passwordMatch: true,
        });
    });

});
```

along with the error message saying the number of calls is 0:

[image]

Where is this going wrong? The functionality in the app works fine.

Comment: You _don't_ mock `setState`. **Don't mock what you don't own**, and the React API is firmly in that category. Test _behaviour_, not _implementation_ - what should the user _see_ if they try to submit with mismatched passwords?

Comment: Ahh I see, if the inputError is true for the specific value then it gives the input a className of 'has-error' and then I just give it some basic red colored border styling  so the user knows there's an issue with that input

Comment: So test that the right class is added, e.g. `expect(screen.getByRole(...)).toHaveClass("has-error")`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to test the React hooks directly, instead, as @jonrsharpe said in the comment, "They do not belong to you". Instead, you can test the actual behavior and as your test description says, check if the error message is displayed.

```
it("should display error message when passwords do not match", async () => {
    const setInputError = jest.fn();
    const props = { setInputError };
    const { getByLabelText, getByText } = render(<SignupPage {...props} />);
    const passwordInput = getByLabelText("pages.login.signup.password");
    const confirmPasswordInput = getByLabelText("pages.login.signup.confirm_password");
    const registerButton = getByText("pages.login.signup.register");
    fireEvent.change(passwordInput, { target: { value: "password1" } });
    fireEvent.change(confirmPasswordInput, { target: { value: "password2" } });
    fireEvent.click(registerButton);

    const errorMessage = getByText("your error text message").toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, noted for future too!